# how to enclose the oracle csv output header in double quotes?

Tags: oracle

I have a query like this, e.g

```
select 
  case 
    when userid is not null then '"A"'
    when userid is null then '""'
  end
as H
from tableName
```

what i want to happen is that, i want the letter H to be enclosed with double quotes
in the csv. I already tried

```
'"'||H||'"' //didn't work
```

also tried

```
"H" //didn't work
```

also tried

```
"""||H||""" //didn't work
```

so how to do this ?, so that I'm gonna have the output with the header enclose in double quotes like e.g

```
"H"
"A"
""
""
"A"
```

because i want the values and the header to be enclosed in double quotes

Comment: How you are writing the csv, is it through the file handling?

Comment: I was just doing manually in the oracle sql developer client and exporting it..problem was solved somehow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not go with double quoted alias name as per my best knowledge in sql. But you can definitely go with single quoted alias name. If you will try below

```
select 
  case 
    when userid is not null then '"A"'
    when userid is null then '""'
  end
as " ""H"""
from tableName;
```

You will have ORA-03001: unimplemented feature error in sql.

But you can get single quoted alias with below query

```
select 
  case 
    when userid is not null then '"A"'
    when userid is null then '""'
  end
as "'H'"
from tableName;
```

In SQL*Plus or sqlplus command line interface, you can use two double-quotes in a row to include a double-quote in a double-quoted string.

```
column h format 9999999999999999999999 HEADING " ""H""";

select 
  case 
    when userid is not null then '"A"'
    when userid is null then '""'
  end
as h
from tableName;
```

Then you will be able to get double quote in alias.

Hope this may help you.

Comment: I guess you're right, I have tried everything and it's really not possible to have a double quote in headers, unless when exporting in sql developer, need to enclose it with double quotes option. but the table database will be quoted twice....what i did is, I just put the double quotes manually..I guess i'll just create a server side script to generate the csv files to avoid the trouble in putting those header double quotes manually..thanks